# How to set a limit of clicking a button when user already click it for 10 times-android

Tags: java, android, button

I have a button called "Save".
When I click it, it will call below coding :

```
public void SaveText(View view){     

            try {
              OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput ("myfilename.txt",MODE_APPEND));


                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                String latt = Double.toString(latitude); 
                String lonn = Double.toString(longitude); 


              String text =(latt+" "+lonn+" "+mydate);
              out.write(text);
              out.write('\n');             

              out.close();

              Toast.makeText(this,"Text Saved !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }

                 catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                //do something if an IOException occurs.
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry Text could't be added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show
    ();
                                           }
```

I want to set the "Save" button unclickable when user already click it for 10 times so that
it will not save more than 10 texts to text file.

**EDIT**

What I have tried so far :

do{

```
        try {
          OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput ("myfilename.txt",MODE_APPEND));

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            String latt = Double.toString(latitude); 
            String lonn = Double.toString(longitude); 


          String text =(latt+" "+lonn+" "+mydate);
          out.write(text);
          out.write('\n');             

          out.close();

          Toast.makeText(this,"Text Saved !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          count++;
          }

             catch (java.io.IOException e) {            
                Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry Text could't be added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show
();
                                       }}

    while(count<9);
    if (count>9){Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Save); btn.setEnabled(false);}


 }
```

The result is when click "Save" button once, it disable my "Save" button without waiting it to be clicked until 10 times.

**NEW CODE**

```
 public void SaveText(View view){    
     if (this.counter <= 10) {

        try {
          OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput ("xy.txt",MODE_APPEND));


            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            String latt = Double.toString(latitude); 
            String lonn = Double.toString(longitude); 


          String text =(latt+" "+lonn+" "+mydate);
          out.write(text);
          out.write('\n');             

          out.close();

          Toast.makeText(this,"Text Saved !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }

             catch (java.io.IOException e) {

                Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry Text could't be added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show
();
                                    }
    this.counter++;     }



 }}
```

All method I have tried but when I click "Save" button for the second time, it will do nothing.

**SOLUTION :**

Thank you very much.
Everyone really help me to solve this.

```
 public void SaveText(View view){    

          if (this.counter <= 10) {
            //to-do coding
                                            }
              this.counter++;

    }

          else{Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Save); btn.setEnabled(false);}  

     }}
```

Comment: And what happens when user clicks 10 times, exits the app and then returns? The counter starts from 0 or 10?

Comment: keep a counter increment on click. check if it reaches 10 and disable the button.

Comment: i have did do while but nothing happens.. it still append my text file @Raghunandan

Comment: Every time user clicks it, it will append the text file.. The text file will show the contain at View when user click button "Display", It will keep update the View when click "Display" button if any new text file being saved. counter starts from 0 to 9.. @m0skit0

Comment: @doraemon I'm assuming you found your answer, people worked hard to help so please mark the one you used to show you appreciation and up-vote those that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the counter of button clicks in your class. Since you didn't specify what your class name, I'll just call it `YourClass`.

```
public class YourClass ... {

     private int buttCounter = 0;
     ...
}
```

Then you need to update and check this counter whenever the button is clicked.

```
public void SaveText(View view){

    if (this.buttCounter <= 10) {
        // Your old method body goes here
        this.buttCounter++;
    }
}
```

This will not deactivate the button, but it will do nothing on button press. If you want to disable the button, you can use `Button.setClickable(false)`, `Button.setEnabled(false)` or even hide it using `Button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

Comment: it do nothing after just once I click button "Save".. @m0skit0

Comment: Works fine for me. I need more details to be able to help you further. For example your button listener. What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Well set a instance variable to hold the clicks and have an onclick listener that increments that variable. Then once it reached that amount change the button properties.

If you'd like further help we'll need to see the whole class to show you where.

Comment: Not global variable, instance variable.

Comment: @doraemon you are not showing us the initialization of the counter, make sure it is 0 to start. Add the incremental ++ on the onclick listener not this function. Show us the listener.... you better off showing the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your click listener.

```
    private int numClicks = 0;
    public void SaveText(View view){
            numClicks++;
            if(numClicks == 10) {
                    view.setEnabled(false);
            }
```

Comment: Awful data encapsulation violation.

Comment: You can make it private, it makes no difference. But as he said it's probably best practice to encapsulate that variable using private. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: *"it makes no difference"* Ah this young unexperienced programmers... :)

Comment: Also this way you will only allow saving 9 files because you increment the counter before creating the file.

Comment: I think this counting shouldn't in SaveText() method,it will be in button click event.

Comment: @ridoy Doesn't matter if button click handler always calls `SaveText()`

Comment: @m0skit0 You are extremely condescending in your responses, lets try to keep it professional.

Comment: "Professional"? This is a Q&A site, I'm not working here... Go read some comments around SO. And keep the humour sense my friend, you're too young to be this stubborn ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that you'll increment at the end of the onclick. In the onclick, before the incrementation, make a condition to check if your variable is equal to 9. If it is equal to 9, make the button disabled.

Edit:

```
int counter = 0;
public void SaveText()
{
   doSomething();

   if(counter == 9)
   {
      myButton.setEnabled(false);
   }
   counter++;
}
```

Comment: And you initialize that variable with which value?

Comment: It hasn't been clicked yet. Initialize it to 0. Alternatively, you can initialize it to 10 and stop when it equals 19.

Comment: i make it.. but it do nothing when i click save button after first time @gobernador

Comment: @gobernador That edit with the variable initialization is much clearer. And variables are not clicked :D